# Using NSArray to store UIWebView for use with UIToolBar

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, nsarray, uitoolbar

I have a WebView, UIToolBar and I have a Next button and Previous button.

I have 6 HTML pages that I need to display in sequence depending on the press of the next or previous button.

So for example: start at HTML page 1, press next and load HTML page 2. Press next and load HTML page 3. and so on.

The UIWebView currently is loaded like this:

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"PrepareEquipment" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
```

I want to be able to press the next button and load the webview with the next HTML page.

How would I do this? Should it be an NSArray or is there a better way?

Help is much appreciated guys.

Stefan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is really a simple problem.

Create 2 attributes : 1 NSArray pageList and 1 int currentPage

First of all you should stock your html page name in an array (in good order)

```
[self.pageList addObject:@"Page1"];
[self.pageList addObject:@"Page2"];
[self.pageList addObject:@"Page3"];
//etc.
```

On click on the arrow just increase or decrease currentPage and then :

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[self.pageList objectAtIndex:currentPage] ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
```

Don't forget to disable your buttons (prev. if currentPage == 0 and next if currentPage == [self.pageList count]-1)

That all, good luck